# can't play video on custom wordpress page?

Tags: wordpress

```
<?php

/* Template Name: testvideo */ 
?>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>

<source src=:"videos/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```

this code works fine when it is played standalone html file but when I use this as wordpress custom page self hosted video does not play but if I use external url video works fine I don't know what is going wrong?

Comment: read [this](https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Media_into_Posts_and_Pages)

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide valid video url to source tag. please try below code.

```
<?php
/* Template Name: testvideo */ 
?>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/videos/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

/* Template Name: testvideo */ 
?>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>

<source src=<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>"/videos/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```